# How to use Nvidia GPU on window docker

Tags: windows, docker, gpu

I'm using docker desktop on window 10 and when I want to use Nvidia GPU to training network in docker. I found it needs to update the windows to preview version to use GPU in docker, but I think the new version system is not stable, so I wonder Is there any other way to use GPU in docker desktop?